# What is the default format for a varbinary in ASP.NET WebAPI v2

Tags: entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I've got a basic ASP.NET WebAPI service using EntityFramework to pull data from a database.  The data in the DB has a column that is varbinary(max) with an image stored in it.  When I call the WebAPI resource I get a string back.  What is the encoding for that string to convert it back to binary?  I've tried ASCII, UTF8, and Base64 and they don't seem to work.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Can you try the `byte[]` as the property type and make the Web API OData to map it as Edm.Binary primitive type?

Answer (score 0):

The EDM type is binary[].  As it turns out the default encoding is Base64.  I tried this at first but was having another issue that masked the solution.